# VF inlineEditSupport - double click not working properly

Tags: apex, visualforce, inlineeditsupport

I have made a VF page with apex inlineEditSupport on (the double click edit thing) an outputField (think of when you pull up a record in SFDC and edit any field by double click.) I have a VF page with a custom controller extension. When I run the code by itself via "www.salesforce.com/apex/myVfPage" the double click to edit works great and I can double click to edit fields.

BUT

when I put the VF page and embed it into my opportunity page layout the double click to edit does not respond. I then hit the "Edit" button I have created, I created the edit but ONLY to rerender a pageBlockSection which seems to fix the problem temporarily.

I want to solve this where when the page layout with the VF page load I can instantly double click to edit, not hit my edit button and then double click to edit.

Here is the VF page "editDAaccount":

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" extensions="AccountEDIT">
    <apex:pageMessages id="showmsg"/>
        <apex:form id="daForm">
          <apex:pageBlock mode="inlineEdit">
            <apex:pageBlockButtons location="both">
                <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save" id="saveButton"/>
                <apex:commandButton action="{!cancel}" id="cancelButton" value="Cancel"/>
                <apex:commandButton value="Edit" reRender="acctStuff"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>

            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
                <apex:outputField value="{!opportunity.Name}">
                    <apex:inlineEditSupport event="ondblclick"/>
                </apex:outputField>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>

            <apex:repeat value="{!Accts}" var="ac">
                <apex:pageBlockSection title="General" showHeader="false" id="acctStuff">
                    <apex:repeat value="{!$ObjectType.Account.FieldSets.judelaw}" var="field">
                        <apex:outputField value="{!ac[Field]}">
                            <apex:inlineEditSupport event="ondblClick"/>
                        </apex:outputField>
                    </apex:repeat>
                </apex:pageBlockSection>
            </apex:repeat>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Here is my apex Class "AccountEDIT":

```
public with sharing class AccountEDIT {
    ApexPages.StandardController stdCon;
    public List<Account> listOfAccts;

    public AccountEDIT (ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
        this.stdCon = stdController;
    }

    public Opportunity getOpportunity() { return (Opportunity)stdCon.getRecord(); }

    public Account getAccts() {
        if((getOpportunity().id != null) && (listOfAccts == null)) {
            DescribeSObjectResult dRes = Account.getSObjectType().getDescribe();
            List<String> fieldNames = new List<String>( dRes.fields.getMap().KeySet() );
            String foo = getOpportunity().Id;
            List<Opportunity> opps = [SELECT Id, Name, AccountID FROM Opportunity WHERE Id =: foo];
            String oppAcctId = opps[0].AccountId;

            String myQ = 
                ' SELECT ' +
                    String.join(fieldNames, ', ') +
                ' FROM ' +
                    dRes.getName() +
                ' WHERE Id = \'' + oppAcctId + '\'';
            System.debug('** my Q: ' + myQ);
            this.listOfAccts = Database.query(myQ);

        }

        return this.listOfAccts[0];
    }

    private boolean updateAcct() {
        boolean r = true;

        if(this.listOfAccts != null) {
            try {
                update this.listOfAccts;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                String msg = e.getMessage();
                System.debug('error yo: ' + msg);
                ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, msg));

                r = false;
            }
        }

        return r;
    }

    public PageReference save() {
        Boolean r = true;
        PageReference pr = Page.editDAaccount;

        if(getOpportunity().Id != null) {
            r = updateAcct();
        } else {
            pr.setRedirect(true);
        }

        if(r == true) {
            stdCon.save();
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.INFO, 'Changes have been...ya whatever....its done'));
        }

        pr.getParameters().put('id', getOpportunity().id);
        return pr;
    }

}
```

Comment: your code is working fine at my DE without clicking on Edit button, can you post with a screenshot. what type of fields you are editing?

Comment: Right so the code works just fine by itself but once it is put into a page layout the double click no longer works unless the edit button is pressed.

Comment: I have checked that it is working fine when I embed VFP in standard page layout which clicking Edit button

Comment: So I don't want to use edit button at all. I'm just using it to rerender. Were you able to make it work embedded without edit button? If so what is different? Thanks

Comment: Without edit button it is working and there are no differences